# Calling stored procedure from another stored procedure with parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure with takes 2 parameters (StudentID and CurrentSmester) as input and return me table with fields :

1. Course Code
2. Update Type
3. Update Id

This stored procedure is created by another team in my office. I can not modify it but at the same point I want to use it in my Webservice (which I am building for android) to make sure data remains consistent.

My requirement is to get :

1. Course Code
2. Update Type
3. Update Id
4. Course Title

Can I create another store procedure which will call that store procedure with parameters as I mentioned, make a join with course table to get course title too.

Is this possible ? If yes can you please guide me through its implementation.

Thanking You and Happy New Year !!

Comment: As per my knowledge, its not possible. why dont you just modify the existing one instead of creating a new one which will have one more column. OR you should create your own separate SP and do whatever you like.

Comment: I can not modify it as it is used by very heavy application and they dont want to add single field to it.

Comment: I can not create separate as i don't want that if later they make any change to their store procedure, it will not be reflected in my store procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert the results from the STORED PROCEDURE into a temp table (table variable or temp table) and them select from that table and join onto the `Courses` table to retrieve the title.

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/04640/1)

Example code

```
CREATE TABLE Courses(
  CourseCode VARCHAR(50),
  CourseName VARCHAR(250)
);
INSERT INTO Courses VALUES ('A','AA'), ('B','BB');

CREATE PROCEDURE OtherTeamsSP(
  @StudentID INT,
  @CurrentSmester INT
)
AS
SELECT 'A' CourseCode,
        'FOO' UpdateType,
        1 UpdateId;

CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure(
  @StudentID INT,
  @CurrentSmester INT
)
AS
CREATE TABLE #SPOutput(
  CourseCode VARCHAR(50),
  UpdateType VARCHAR(50),
  UpdateId INT
 )

INSERT INTO #SPOutput
EXEC OtherTeamsSP @StudentID, @CurrentSmester

SELECT *
FROM #SPOutput s INNER JOIN
    Courses c ON s.CourseCode = c.CourseCode
DROP TABLE #SPOutput
```

Calling the new SP

```
EXEC MyProcedure 1,2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, and your solution do make some sense but i have few question.

Comment: Will i be creating temp table within my store procedure ?

Comment: Yes, the temp table is within the SP, you can also replace the temp table with a table variable if the row count is not to large or if you ave permission issues

Answer (score 1):

Create a new stored procedure , insert the results coming back from your existing stored procedure into a temp table, join your Course table with that temp table and you are good to go ,

something like this.....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_NewProc 
@StudentID INT ,
@CurrentSmester INT 
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp 
(
CourseCode [DataType],
UpdateType [DataType],
Update Id  [DataType]
)

INSERT INTO #temp 
EXEC existsting_proc @StudentID , @CurrentSmester


SELECT t.* , C.CourseTitle
FROM #temp t INNER JOIN CourseTable C  on <join Condition>

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE #temp

END
```

Answer (score 0):

-- First Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FirstSP
@MyFirstParam INT
AS
DECLARE @MyFirstParamValue INT
SELECT @MyFirstParamValue = @MyFirstParam * @MyFirstParam
RETURN (@MyFirstParamValue)
GO
```

-- Second Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SecondSP
@SecondParam INT
AS
DECLARE @SecondParamValue INT
SELECT @SecondParamValue = @SecondParam * @SecondParam
RETURN (@SecondParamValue)
GO
```

-- Pass One Stored Procedure's Result as Another Stored Procedure's Parameter

```
DECLARE @FirstValue INT, @SeondValue INT
```

-- First SP

```
EXEC @FirstValue = FirstSP 5
```

-- Second SP

```
EXEC @SeondValue = SecondSP @FirstValue
SELECT @SeondValue SecondSP
GO
```

-- Clean up

```
DROP PROCEDURE FirstSP
DROP PROCEDURE SecondSP
GO
```